# Selenium not working on Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I installed Selenium on my system using 'pip install selenium' and it works great on Mac Console. But when I tried using selenium in my project on Pycharm, I got an error that No module named Selenium exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you [configured your interpreter](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Configuring+Interpreters+with+PyCharm) in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what I was doing wrong. My Mac Terminal and Pycharm were using different Python that I installed on my system, so I changed the path on Pycharm interpreter to the local path where Selenium was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use python 2.x and 3.x on your computer and you configured in pycharm other then the one you use in console? If it is so then pip could install selenium to python 2.x and in pycharm you are using 3.x or the other way round.